# If you have to use an accessor function two times in a block of code,

Tags: optimization

I have a question. Suppose you have to call a function twice in a block of code, and are guaranteed for it to return the same value both times. Should you optimize your code by creating an extra variable?

Example:

Should

```
foo1(v.length()); // foo1 doesn't modify v.length()
foo2(v.length());
```

be changed to

```
int vlen = v.length();
foo1(vlen);
foo2(vlen);
```

for optimability?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

The increase in performance for one execution of the hypothetical code block where the above code appears might be negligible, but consider that if you have a repetitive loop in which the code block appears, you might see a *small* performance gain, because there would be less "call/ret" spaghetti stringing in the code.  Yet, with the faster processors on the market today, allow me to emphasize that the performance increase is *small*.  Also, the compiled code block is probably smaller by a byte or two in the version where you only called `v.length()` once.

So again, a *small* increase in efficiency that is negligible.  Yet, it's still the best practice to optimize like this -- especially if you have something like a `for` loop, where the performance gain is roughly multiplied by the number of times that the unaltered value returned by the function is utilized and multiplied, the performance gain could prove non-negligible.

```
unsigned int something = function();
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < something; i ++ )
{
    ...
}
```

rather than

```
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < function(); i ++ )
{
    ...
}
```